# Silverlight Navigation Between Multiple Projects

Tags: silverlight

This may be simple but we continue to struggle with this.

We are using Silverlight and MVVM and let's say we have two silverlight class libraries each with one view and view model.

If we have a button on each view that says go to the other view, how do we setup navigation to show the other view/view model without creating circular references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using MVVM, the proper was is to use the event aggregator.  Each view model could trigger a "NavigationRequested" event, and then the top level should listen for that event and navigate accordingly.  As a simple example:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    IEventPublisher publisher = new EventPublisher();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel(publisher);
    var view1 = new View1 { DataContext = viewModel };
    var view2 = new View2 { DataContext = viewModel };

    this.RootVisual = view1;
    view1.DataContext = viewModel;

    publisher.Get<NavigationRequested>()
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Select(item => item.ViewName)
        .Subscribe(name => RootVisual = name == "View1" ? view1 : view2);

    this.RootVisual = view1;
}
```

Note that the syntax I'm using above is from [this event aggregator that uses the RX extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756787/1001985), but the same idea should apply regardless of which MVVM framework, if any, you're using.